# Yup cyclic dependency: Two fields mutually requiring each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, yup

I have the following Yup validation schema

```
 const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string(),
  services: Yup.array(Yup.string().oneOf(SERVICES, "Invalid service!")),
  locations: Yup.array(Yup.string().oneOf(LOCATIONS, "Invalid location!")),
  distance: Yup.number()
    .typeError("Invalid distance!")
    .positive("Invalid distance!")
    .when("userFormattedAddress", {
      is: (val) => !!val,
      then: Yup.number().required(),
      otherwise: Yup.number(),
    }),
  userFormattedAddress: Yup.string("Invalid user location!").when("distance", {
    is: (val) => !!val,
    then: Yup.string().required(),
    otherwise: Yup.string(),
  }),
  userCoordinates: Yup.array(
    Yup.number("Invalid user location!").positive("Invalid user location!")
  ),
});
```

The desired behaviour is that when a distance is entered, the user must enter an address, and when a user enters an address , they must specify a distance too. However, I run into a cyclic dependency... Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer:

```
 const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
 name: Yup.string(),
 services: Yup.array(Yup.string().oneOf(SERVICES, "Invalid service!")),
 locations: Yup.array(Yup.string().oneOf(LOCATIONS, "Invalid location!")),
 distance: Yup.number()
   .typeError("Invalid distance!")
   .positive("Invalid distance!")
   .when("userFormattedAddress", {
     is: (val) => !!val,
     then: Yup.number().required(),
     otherwise: Yup.number(),
   }),
 userFormattedAddress: Yup.string("Invalid user location!").when("distance", {
   is: (val) => !!val,
   then: Yup.string().required(),
   otherwise: Yup.string(),
 }),
 userCoordinates: Yup.array(
   Yup.number("Invalid user location!").positive("Invalid user location!")
 ),
}, ["distance", "userFormattedAddress"]);
```

where you need to pass the fields in an array as the noSortedEdges argument

Comment: did you found out what does that array that goes as second argument to shape() stands for?

Comment: Relevant discussion: [https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/287#issuecomment-428108626](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/287#issuecomment-428108626) - simply add an array (with the inter-dependent items) as the second positional parameter to Yup.shape() and it will avoid cyclical dependency.